# How to not lose quality when stretch in PictureBox?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I'd loaded 10x10 (px) image into PictureBox. When I'd set up SizeMode property to Stretch image resized, but it losed quality.

[image]

I know in lazarus I can have done this:

```
Image3.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('...............');
Image3.Stretch := true;
// Image3 is object of class TImage
```

And image will be streched without any loses of quality.

How I can achieve same in C# Windows Forms?

Comment: You cannot stretch a `Bitmap` without quality loss. This is only possible for `vector graphics`

Comment: How lazarus do this then?

Comment: What is Lazarus? A Delphi variant as it seems? Look into its manual to see which resizing algorithms it uses.

Comment: I don't know lazarus. Maybe it has an algorithm for vectorizing the image. For a simple image like this, it should be no problem for such an algorithm

Comment: Judging by the simplicity of the image in your example, I would say that a potential reason why "Lazarus" is able to do this is that it scales using nearest neighbour. This would "work" with the black and white pixelated image you have there. Unsure if you can ask PictureBox to use it though, you may have to do the scaling yourself using the Graphics class.

Comment: You'll have to create a bigger bitmap yourself to control the way the image is enlarged.  Use Graphics.DrawImage() with InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor to get a sharp edge instead of the interpolated edges.